# Kapt Kotlin incremental annotation processing not working

Tags: android, kotlin, kapt

I have been trying to enable incremental annotation processing in one of my android projects. I am using kotlin-kapt plugin "1.8.22". AFAIK, this plugin already has incremental annotation set as true by default. (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details)

When I run the build command -

> ../gradlew aDeb -Pkapt.verbose=true -x lint --warning-mode all --debug

I get the following output -

```
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Show processor stats: false
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Verbose mode: true
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Info as warnings: false
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Use light analysis: false
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Correct error types: false
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Dump default parameter values: false
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Map diagnostic locations: false
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Strict mode: false
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Detect annotation processors in compile classpath: true
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] **Incremental annotation processing (apt mode): false**
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Strip @Metadata annotations from stubs: false
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Keep KDoc comments in stubs: false
2023-12-22T08:31:44.413+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] Use JVM IR backend: false
```

This say that Incremental annotation processing (apt mode) is false. Does it mean Incremental annotation processing is not working?